# Common usecase diagram for games

Tags: diagram, use-case, 2d-games

I developed a simple 2D puzzle game (like "bejeweled"). It can be played in two modes - "campaign" and "quick game". "Campaign" mode has several levels. Player can save his progress when quit a campaign level. "Quick game" mode just generates random level and can't be saved. In both modes player can pause the game and a menu will show up. After completing a level (no matter game mode) a statistic window will show up with buttons for exit and next level (if "campaign mode").

**Main menu structure:**

- Continue (if there is a saved progress)
- New game (game starts from first level; clears the progress)
- Quick game
- Exit

**Pause menu structure:**

- Continue (resumes the game)
- Back (goes to main menu and saves the progress if it's "campaign" mode)

I have to create an usecase diagram, but I have difficulties. I have made usecase diagrams for windows based software (where there are forms, buttons, textboxes, etc.), but never for games. **How should look an use case diagram for a video game** (and more particularly for my kind of game)**?** After that I have to create activity diagrams to explain the whole process in details... if it's important for the use case diagram.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try some of these links:

These are pretty good examples of designs...

http://xnagamedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/03/use-case-diagram.html

https://github.com/ryanalane/Sudoku-Game/blob/master/documentation/Use%20Case%20Diagram/sudoku_usecasediagram.png

This is a detailed paper on UML for games...

http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/perdita/guide.pdf

This is a pretty good discussion about the use of UML in game design, in general...

http://www.gamedev.net/topic/192120-uml-for-games/